# Are there any inherit benefits to initializing an SQL database though script files or through java code?

Tags: java, sql, database

If I have a java application that uses an SQL database and the application is being used for the first time, are there any inherit benefits to initializing (i.e., create the database and all necessary tables, initial record inserts, etc.) the database through SQL script files or through java code?

Initial things that come to mind are user privileges on a machine, speed, reliability/stability.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the application would function without it's requisite database tables, initial records, etc - so what is your proposed alternative to performing those setup steps without SQL scripts files or Java code?

Comment: My question is if it's better to use java code to create the database and tables using java statements, or to maybe have some supporting batch file that executes the SQL script files and initialize the DB that way.

Comment: It depends upon your specific needs, but the bottom line is a) if you put all your "create" and "load" statements into a java program, you have to write a java program and the SQL statements or b) If you use a client utility (e.g. psql for Postgres), you only have to write the SQL statements. The other things should be the roughly the same (java or script, you still need the machine, privileges and so on). Many databases provide bulk data upload capabilities that are generally more efficient than SQL inserts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No difference to the database

Whether you create tables and columns and such via JDBC or via SQL scripts, in both cases it is simply SQL commands being fed into the database engine. So, no, the database does not care which way you do it.

> user privileges on a machine, speed, reliability/stability

You must have appropriate user privileges and database access whether invoking JDBC or running scripts. I see no issue there.

As for speed, again, you end up sending SQL statements to the database engine, so no difference. Ditto for reliability and stability.

There are strategies for speed such as working locally on the server machine (not over network), and [bulk loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_insert). Those strategies apply whether going through JDBC or SQL scripts.

## Database migration tools

You should learn about [database migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) tools.

For example, my favorite [*Flyway*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)) is a Java-based tool that will automatically run a suite of SQL scripts. Optionally Flyway can invoke Java classes you wrote to manipulate the database, for complicated scenarios where SQL is not enough. So you get the best of both routes in your Question, going through [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) or going through SQL scripts.

Flyway works by automatically creating a table for its own housekeeping. In that table it tracks what scripts have been run. Each time you invoke Flyway, it checks what scripts were previously run and compares that to all the scripts currently found. Any new scripts discovered are then executed and tracked. Ditto for any database-manipulation Java classes you wrote.

Notice how useful this approach is in development and testing. Whenever you desire, you can start a fresh database and ramp it up to any point in the evolution of your app simply by taking away or adding various scripts. Testers can add extra scripts to load data to create a particular use-case scenario. All this can be done repeatedly and with automated tools.

Also useful in production. By completely automating the updating of the database structure, you eliminate human error. Deploying will be a calmer process. Of course, for [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), a database migration tool is practically required.

You can invoke Flyway via Java, typically during the initialization phase of your app launching. Or, you may choose to invoke Flyway via command-line tools on the console or as part of your build process. The console tools wrap Flyway with a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) and [JDBC drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) thereby hiding the fact Flyway runs on Java. So even a non-Java shop can make full use of Flyway.

Migration tools have advanced by great leaps in recent years. Consider adopting *Flyway*, [*Liquibase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase), or some such tool.